# No compile time error when casting to the wrong type

Tags: c#

My question is regarding Type Casting in different interfaces

Suppose I have an interface

```
public interface I
{
    void method();
}
```

A class implementing it

```
public class C : I
{
    public void method()
    {
    }
}
```

I have another interface

```
public interface I1
{
    void method1();
}
```

Now if i do something like this

```
C c1 = new C();
((I1)c1).method1();
```

It throws a run time exception rather than a compile time error

Comment: It is obvious , how does compiler will know that you have not implemented that interface in that class ,  what you want

Comment: @paritosh - opposite is true - compiler does indeed know that `I1` is not implemented by that class `C`, but see Scott Chamberlain for case of derived class.

Comment: but not until it is sealed correct?

Comment: @paritosh it knows `C` does not implement `method1` (that is why you would get a error if you tried to use `method1` without casting), but it can't know "for sure" that it is not implemented somewhere else until runtime unless the class is marked `sealed`. Therefor it does not give any errors at compile time.

Comment: @paritosh Compiler does know about the interfaces implemented by class that is why there is a compile time error when we do not define all the methods in our class which are present in our interface

Comment: @ScottChamberlain :That was exactly what I was saying,

Answer (score 12):

Because `C` is not marked `sealed` I could potentially do this

```
public D : C, I1
{
    public void method1()
    {
    }
}
```

Which would make the following code perfectly legal.

```
C c1 = new D();
((I1)c1).method1();
```

If `C` is marked `sealed` you should get a compile time error as there can't exist a more derived class that could be implementing the interface.

```
public sealed class C : I
{
    public void method()
    {
    }
}

//You should now get the compile time error "Cannot convert type 'SandboxConsole.C' to 'SandboxConsole.I1'"
```

Comment: same thing could happen in case of classes but it does throw a compile time error rather than exception even if we do not make class sealed.